# Classify database model of Redis

Tags: database, redis

Can we classify the Redis database implementation to one of the standards that already exist? Or is Redis using it's own model for this?

On Wikipedia I found the following Common models for databases:

- Flat
- Hierarchical
- Dimensional
- Network
- Relational
- Entity–relationship
- Graph
- Object-oriented
- Entity–attribute–value

Comment: as redis is a key value store, it will probably fit into flat or entity attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis is a pretty wild mixture of different models. As a first approximation, it is flat: on the top level, it is a key-value store.

But Redis also offers more than a simple key-value store. Hashes, for example, are entity-attribute-value stores. There are also extensions that add graph functionality. And many tutorials (and the official documentation) show ways to use Redis for relational data.

Comment: Thank you, so they implemented a customized key-value model interface over a flat model to keep speed? Or are the exact implementation details a secret?